# Distribution of the ratio of two poisson processes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I have two Poisson counting processes that generate events of type 1 or 2 at some independent rates $r_1$ and $r_2$. In a fixed time interval $T$ I count $N_1\sim\textrm{Poisson}(r_1 T)$ type 1 events, and $N_2\sim\textrm{Poisson}(r_2T)$ type two events, and I form the fraction $f=\frac{N_1}{N_2}$.

What is the distribution of $f$?

If I run this test twice, how would I go about constructing a t-test to see if the second value of $f$ I get is significantly different from the first?

I found this paper: https://ttu-ir.tdl.org/bitstream/handle/2346/59954/31295007034522.pdf?sequence=1

I am hoping that there is a nicer expression for the distribution that I can work with, or maybe an approximation that works well in the limit of large values of $N_1$ and $N_2$.

Alternatively, is there a different function $g$ of $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that $g(N_1,N_2)$ is Gaussian distributed?

Comment: As described in the paper that you cited, the denominator must follow a truncated Poisson to avoid the problem of having zero counts at the denominator. Here you can find a Bayesian approach https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0606247.pdf (Sec. 2.2).

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95473/problem-when-using-ratio-of-two-poisson-distributed-varialbes

Comment: No matter what the function $g$ may be, either $g(N_1,N_2)$ has a discrete distribution (or it has no distribution at all if $g$ is not measurable).  Thus it cannot possibly be Gaussian.  But why not just record both $N_1$ and $N_2,$ which doesn't lose half of the information available to you?

Comment: @whuber right, silly of me. But for my application, all the information I need to get an answer is the ratio of the two, which I am currently just calibrating experimentally. I suppose I could set it up as a 2D plot with regions for making a positive call over a negative one that would obviate the need for forming the ratio, though. I think that changes the nature of the error estimation problem I have without necessarily simplifying it